# if-else statement behaving incorrectly

Tags: c++, if-statement

So i have two functions. one function checks to see if the given sides form a right triangle. The problem is that when I call the function in the if-else statement in classify, I always get "Not a right Triangle" even though the value of isRightTriangle(sides) is true.

```
bool isRightTriangle(int sides[])
{
    std::sort(sides, sides+3);

    if((pow(sides[0],2) + pow(sides[1],2)) == pow(sides[2],2))
        return true;
    return false;
}

void classify(int sides[], ofstream &outfile)
{
    int largest(int []);
    void typeOfTriangle(int [], ofstream &);
    bool isRightTriangle(int []);

    outfile << "Largest Side: " << largest(sides) << endl;
    typeOfTriangle(sides,outfile);

    if(isRightTriangle(sides))
        outfile << "Right Triangle\n\n\n";
    else
        outfile << "Not a Right Triangle\n\n\n";
}
```

Comment: What does `sides[]` contain in your test?

Comment: @RobertHarvey 3 integers. my isRightTriangle function works correctly. I've tested it and it does indeed print 0 or 1 on the appropiate numbers.

Comment: $5 says the if else is working just fine :P

Comment: What is the point of calling `isRightTriangle(sides);` twice?

Comment: You have a `typeOfTriangle` method - does that do anything relevant?

Comment: It would be really nice to have an unit test which reproduces the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that typeOfTriangle or largest is not modifying your array?

Comment: @JustinMeiners I just entered 3 4 5 and it said "Not a right triangle" you owe me lunch.

Comment: @AmberRoxanna have you ran it with a breakpoint?

Comment: @AmberRoxanna haha I didn't say your righttriangle function was correct, I think the if else will work however. Compiler bugs in standard control structures are rare.

Comment: http://ideone.com/DgU9Ze. Works correct here

Comment: Maybe instituting some const correctness could find an error in a function we can't see?

Comment: @zdan yes it's sorting the array from smallest to largest. that's what the std::sort() function does right?

Comment: In your `isRightTriangle()` function, your sort should be `std::sort(0,3,sides)` if you're sorting the first 3 elements.

Comment: if you give it 3,4,5 should be wrong? No? Look at the `std::sort(sides, sides+3);`

Comment: One needs to see the inputs and outputs printed -- copied/pasted directly from the console.

Comment: @RiaD that's so odd, that proves there is nothing wrong with the actual code ?

Comment: Some routine debugging would flesh this out quicker than us trying to guess.  You can start by printing out the contents of the sorted array, to verify that the sort is actually working properly.  Failing that, print out the results of the `pow` functions.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem that doesn't exist.


Comment: Is is valid to use std::sort on `int[]`?  (I'm not a C++ guru, so I'm not familiar with that.)

Comment: And, as potatoswatter suggests, `pow` appears to be a double function, and is not guaranteed to produce exact results.

Comment: @HotLicks absolutely, if you know the size of the array

Comment: I'm going to try it without the pow() function

Comment: So if you use the power function even with integers it returns a floating point number ?

Comment: @JustinMeiners I owe you $5

Comment: @AmberRoxanna Yes, by default `double`… but I don't see how that could cause a problem given 3, 4, 5.

Comment: @Skippy i'm only 16, I make $5 work for me all the time lol. I wish I had a job.

Answer (score 8):

Floating point arithmetic doesn't generally produce perfectly precise results, but `==` checks for exact equality. Instead of comparing `a == b`, use `abs( a - b ) < precision_limit`. This essentially applies to floating-point arithmetic in all languages.

This doesn't explain why it would fail for `3, 4, 5`, but there appears to be a *lot* of code you're not showing us. It would be a very good idea to have `isRightTriangle` print the numbers it's analyzing before the `if`.

(By the way, now I see you're passing integers to `pow`. In this case, imprecise results can only occur for very large numbers, and the `precision_limit` would be at least one.)

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because "doesn't generally" doesn't mean "never."

Comment: Or, in other words, luck ;)

Comment: Presumably, the IDEONE compiler is standards compliant; unless we're talking about undefined behavior,  it should succeed or fail in exactly the same way.

Comment: @RobertHarvey floating point determinism? I thought unless you set strict standards compliant in the compiler, the calculations could be different on different machines. Also it might work with a few contrived numbers, but a float a little bit more off due to inaccuracies of previous calculations that should work will fail.

Comment: @JustinMeiners: It's not like we're talking about the fifteenth decimal place here.  In any event, it's essentially multiplication of integer mantissas, not division.  The results should be exact anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Isn't that enough for == to fail vs epsilon? a single decimal place? (Im not super knowledgable about the details so im not being a jerk here - genuine question).

Comment: @Skippy: Yes. It's also equivalent to `return pow(sides[0],2) + pow(sides[1],2) == pow(sides[2],2);`.

Comment: @JustinMeiners Well, I'm willing to concede that the Pow function could be doing something mathematically funky.  But even if the triangle sides were floats already, you should still be able to multiply integers stored in them precisely (provided they aren't too large).

Comment: Guys… calm down. FP math is deterministic among desktop CPUs, but the people testing the program aren't. If someone can see further past the lack of information in the question, *then* please post your own answer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I'm calm.  Anyone else here not calm?  I've got a bucket full of ice water here that you can use.

Comment: All i can say is that by multiplying the integer by itself worked and using the pow function didn't work. It apparently worked on IDEONE, but i guess it does depend on the CPU

Comment: @AmberRoxanna Is `pow` working at all? What if you simply print the result of `pow(2,2)`? It's possible you haven't included the right header and your compiler is being too tolerant.

Comment: @Potatoswatter i've included cmath.

Comment: @AmberRoxanna `<cmath>` gets you `std::pow`. Did you also do `using namespace std;`?

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, you're using floating point values and expecting exact results. Since you're only ever squaring the numbers (`pow(x, 2)`) you should just multiply them together instead. That's usually faster than pow, even for floats, and it works for any type of number.

Comment: In C++, `std::pow` is overloaded for `int` exponents and this should come out the same as manual multiplication. However, I'm not sure we know that's the `pow` she's calling.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Among other things, it depends on the implementation of `pow`.  It could special-case integer exponents, or it could use a series approximation for everything.